# MySQLI how to insert a form into database by language select

Tags: php, mysqli

Im having an issue with form method.

How can I insert a form value in the database in different table by language select.
I have in my database the tables called article_en / articles_ro ,and when I chose with select english I want the values to be inserted in the article_en

Also when  I select the language its not staying selected.
And if I write something in the inputs and chose a language the inputs are being cleared.

PS:Im a newby , I am still learning.

[image]

[image]

This is the language select code

```
<?php
define("LANG",$_GET['lang']);
include('../db.php');

function select_langs(){
    global $conn;
    echo'<h2 class="box-title">Select the language where you want to the article</h2>
        <select id="select_language">
        <option selected disabled hidden value=""></option>';
    $get_languages = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT lang,title from `languages`") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_languages)){
        if($row['title'] == $_GET['lang']){
            echo'<option value="insert_article.php?lang='.$row['lang'].'" selected>'.$row['title'].'</option>'; 
        }
        else{
            echo'<option value="insert_article.php?lang='.$row['lang'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo'</select>';

}
?>
```

And this is the insert code.

```
<?php 
include('./lang.php');
include('../db.php');
define("LANG",$_GET['lang']);
select_langs();

// extract data from form; store in variable
$title =  $_GET['title'];
$link = $_GET['link'];

if (!empty($title) and !empty($link ) and !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    // Define the query to inser the song request
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `articles_".LANG."`(title , link)VALUES (".$title.", ".$link.")"; 
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#select_language").bind("change",function(){var n=$(this).val();return""!=n&&(window.location=n),!1});
</script>
<form action="insert_article.php" method="get">
    <label id="first">title:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="title"><br/>
    <label id="first">link:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="link"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ajax to send the details to the php to insert it in your database. It's just easier.

```
var select_language= document.getElementById("select_language").value;      
var title= document.getElementById("title").value;
var link= document.getElementById("link").value;

var data= {select_language: select_language,title: title,link:link};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,   

        success: function(html) 
        {              
                console.log (html);          
                alert("Success");
        },
          error: function (html) 
          {
              console.log (html);
              alert("Failure");

        }

    });
```

insert.php

```
include '../dbconfig.php';

$select_language= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['select_language']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['title']);
$link= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['link']);

$query = "your insert query";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Abdullah , hmm I dont think ajax is really necesarly here , I think the normal form method should work , I just dont know whats wrong there.But I will keep trying , thanks for your help :)